# Split Comma Seperated Values into Rows with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as per below

**Names**

```
NameID |   Name  | NickNames
--------------------------
   1   | Richard | Rich, Dick
   2   |   Sam   | Samuel, Samantha, Sammy
   3   |   John  | Jonathan, Johnny
```

And so on...

I have an iterative function already that loops through all rows in this table, and I have the ID of the row at which the loop currently is. I would like to delete all rows from the table where the `'Name'` column is included in the current rows `'NickNames'` column.

For example, row 4 might be:

```
    4   |  Johnathan | NULL
```

I would like for this row to be deleted because 'Johnathan' appears in row 3's NickNames.

Essentially I am trying to select the NickNames column as a series of rows as opposed to its raw CSV-like data. Pretty much the opposite of [This Blog Post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/21/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column-part-2/)

In my eyes it looks something like:

```
DELETE FROM Names WHERE Name IN (SELECT NickNames FROM Names WHERE NameID=@RowID);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should happen if "Johnny" is the Name of entry 5 with a Nickname of "John"?  Should both NameID 3 "John" and NameID 5 "Johnny" be deleted?

Comment: @PaulWilliams In my head, entry 5 will be deleted once the loop hits entry 3 and thus never matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop to do this.  I admit the following may not be the fastest, but it is a single statement:

```
delete from names n
    where exists (select 1
                  from names n2
                  where ',' + n2.nicknames + ',' like '%,' + n.name + ',%' and
                        n2.nameid <> n.nameid
                 );
```

Note:  you shouldn't be storing lists of things in a comma-delimited list.  Relational databases should have only one value per column.  A junction table is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that works better than I'd hoped for. 
I'm aware of the inherent issues with storing comma-delimited values in a single column but in this case because of my db it's a much cleaner approach and it shouldn't cause performance issues due to ridiculous number of table scans as I won't really use it that way